# what tells 32-bit gcc on a 64-bit system, to make 64-bit binary

Tags: gcc

I have a 64-bit system, but gcc is 32-bits and when I do

```
>./gcc -c foobar.c
```

it makes `foobar.o` which is 64-bits.  OK, but how does it know to do that?  Based on what environment setting does it know to produce 64-bit object, and where is that documented??

Come to think about it, it is strange that it does that, is it not??  But `file` utility clearly says, gcc is 32 bits and foobar.o is 64 bits. ( I moved everything to the same directory so it would not be confused.  )

I also checked the 3 dynamically linked libraries that it reads: libc, libm and libz and they are also all 32 bits.

To clarify, I don't want to know, *how* to make it do 32 bits.  I want to know, *what* is it looking at *now* that it makes it do 64.  That is my question, not how to force it the other way around.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the gcc binary is a 32 bit executable ?

Comment: @nos yes I checked (with `file` utility), in fact, I moved that `gcc` binary myself from a 32-bit setup (don't ask why).

Comment: Have you tried with -m64 ?

Comment: Presumably you didn't move binutils, so at a guess the assembler produces 64 bit elf object files, despite the compiler generating 32 bit code. I would not expect moving a 32 bit toolchain to a 64 bit platform to "just work".

Comment: @nos  the compile command is _only_ reading 5 files:  gcc, libc libm libz and foobar.c  .  All these binaries are 32 bit.  I _know_ for sure it is not reading any other file.

Comment: @perencia not sure what you mean, I gave you the command, it uses nothing explicit

Comment: Does compiling with `-v` give any hint?

Comment: @MakrGaleck But your compiler will run other programs too. e.g. the assembler. If the assembler is not instructed to do otherwise, it will create an elf 64 bit object file if you are on a 64 bit platform, which can happen when you mix a 32 bit gcc with a 64 bit assembler (the assembler belongs to the binutils package). In normal circumstances, 32 bit gcc running on a 64 bit platform is built to specifically execute a 32 bit assembler, or pass special flags to the assembler to produce 32 bit object files. Whether that's the issue you're experiencing or something else, I don't know.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your comments.  As best I can tell, the compiler was configured, during its own build, to make 64 bit binaries.  But not sure.

Answer (score 0):

When GCC is configured three different systems can be specified:

- build: - the system where GCC is going to be built (probably not
  relevant to your question)
- host: - the system where GCC is going to
  be executed (32 bit in your case)
- target: the system where binaries, produced by GCC are going to be executed (64 bit in your case)

You can see how your GCC was configured by running:

```
gcc -v
```

command (look for --{build,host,target} options.